# Steam Controller thinks it has 2 hats?

Tags: sdl2, joystick, gamepad

Is there any reason why a Steam Controller would think it has two hats?

[image: steam controller]

The pad on the left is HAT 0, as expected. Note that the pad on the right is not a HAT/DPAD, it is two **axes** (Axis2 and Axis3) also, as expected.

```
03000000de2800000211000011010000 "Steam Controller" axes:4 buttons:21 hats:2 balls:0
```

Still, [SDL_JoystickNumHats()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_JoystickNumHats) returns 2. And bottom hat values on change if a trigger is pressed?

[Tested](https://askubuntu.com/a/368711/107996) with latest SDL 2.0.14 version.

I think ultimately, this info comes from the kernel via ioctl **JSIOCGAXMAP** that identifies the triggers as HAT, not as triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, `hid-steam` maps Steam Controller inputs to these input events:

```
ABS_HAT2Y: left trigger
ABS_HAT2X: right trigger
ABS_X/ABS_HAT0X: X value
ABS_Y/ABS_HAT0Y: Y value
ABS_RX: right-pad X value
ABS_RY: right-pad Y value
BTN_TR2: right trigger fully pressed
BTN_TL2: left trigger fully pressed
BTN_TR: right shoulder
BTN_TL: left shoulder
BTN_Y: button Y
BTN_B: button B
BTN_X: button X
BTN_A: button A
BTN_DPAD_UP: left-pad up
BTN_DPAD_RIGHT: left-pad right
BTN_DPAD_LEFT: left-pad left
BTN_DPAD_DOWN: left-pad down
BTN_SELECT: menu left
BTN_MODE: steam logo
BTN_START: menu right
BTN_GEAR_DOWN: left back lever
BTN_GEAR_UP: right back lever
BTN_THUMBR: right-pad clicked
BTN_THUMB: left-pad touched
BTN_THUMB2: right-pad touched
BTN_THUMBL: joystick clicked
```

This mapping follows the [Linux Gamepad Specification](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/gamepad.html) which specifies how gamepad trigger buttons (named ZL and ZR in the spec) should be mapped to input event codes.

> Triggers:
>
> Trigger buttons can be available as digital or analog buttons or both. User- space must correctly deal with any situation and choose the most appropriate mode.
> Upper trigger buttons are reported as BTN_TR or ABS_HAT1X (right) and BTN_TL or ABS_HAT1Y (left). Lower trigger buttons are reported as BTN_TR2 or ABS_HAT2X (right/ZR) and BTN_TL2 or ABS_HAT2Y (left/ZL).
> If only one trigger-button combination is present (upper+lower), they are reported as “right” triggers (BTN_TR/ABS_HAT1X).
> (ABS trigger values start at 0, pressure is reported as positive values)

`hid-steam` maps the triggers to both `BTN_TR2`/`BTN_TL2` and `ABS_HAT2X`/`ABS_HAT2Y`, which causes SDL2 to detect another Hat Switch.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, of course, is that the Steam Controller's D-Pad isn't actually a D-Pad (with 9 possible input states), it's a touchpad (with two continuous axes). The hid-steam driver implies this by indicating that ABS_HAT0X/Y have a range of -32767 .. 32767, but SDL seems to ignore that and treat it like a regular hat, where `Y < 0 => UP`, `X > 0 => RIGHT`, etc.

This in turn makes the D-Pad all but unusable via SDL: it is impossible to touch the pad perfectly centered on either axis, so in practice SDL will only ever report the hat to be in the corners; trying to touch "UP" will waver between UP-LEFT and UP-RIGHT depending whether your finger is just barely left or right of center on the touchpad.

I'm in the midst of trying to find a solution to this problem (which arose for me in the context of RetroPie's version of EmulationStation) but haven't found the right place to address it yet. There may be an environment variable or some other way to make SDL handle this input correctly, or it may require a patch to notice that (for example) the "hat" input range is far wider than -1 / 0 / 1 and to just expose it as an axis instead.

(I've [raised this issue with SDL](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/5207), so hopefully this will be fixed in a future release.)