# Stride: Gamepad (DS4) Input Not Working in CSharpBeginner Example

Tags: input, sdl, stride

I have only Microsoft build tools and Visual Studio Code installed (not Visual Studio). The CSharpBeginner example from the Stride Game Studio seems to generate, build and run fine using the Game Studio and the project also seems to open, build, and run okay from Visual Studio Code.

It looks like the only thing that doesn't work is controller input in the Virtual Buttons scene. The Visual Studio Code build shows a warning about SDL in the terminal:

```
EXEC : warning 2.150s: [YamlAssemblyRegistry] Assembly [SDL2-CS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] has not been processed by assembly processor with --serialization flags. [DataContract] 
aliases won't be available. [D:\dev\StrideProjects\CSharpBeginner\CSharpBeginner.Windows\CSharpBeginner.Windows.csproj]
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to deal with this? Thanks.

Edit - the project is:

https://github.com/stride3d/stride/tree/master/samples/Tutorials/CSharpBeginner

I just created it from the list of examples given when launching the Game Studio. The only thing I changed was the path to `CSharpBeginner.Windows.dll` in `.vscode/launch.json`. I'm not sure if these files were generated by Stride or Visual Studio Code but wherever it came from it seems to have gotten it wrong. Actually I think it worked before that change in Game Studio but not Code.

Comment: That warning appears to be associated w/ a [known open bug](https://github.com/stride3d/stride/issues/938). It's not clear to me whether or not it has any connection w/ the gamepad input not working. We probably need more info to help you troubleshoot this. Can you include or link to the code for that example?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited the question with more info.

Comment: Thanks for including the extra info. Just to verify the specifics, is [this](https://github.com/stride3d/stride/blob/master/samples/Tutorials/CSharpBeginner/CSharpBeginner/CSharpBeginner.Game/Code/VirtualButtonsDemo.cs) the code in question? And if so, is it only the gamepad that is unresponsive?

Comment: Yes that is the code. Keyboard and mouse work fine and I just noticed that an off brand XBox controller works, but not a DS4. Also I saw the specific build requirements on Github. I installed the specific versions listed and the build warning went away. Specifically installed these: .NET Framework 4.7.2 targeting pack, 
MSVC v142 - VS2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.26), 
C++/CLI support for v142 build tools (v14.26)

Comment: I solved the build warning, but input still doesn't work with the DS4 controller. I've successfully used the DS4 via SDL wrapper in other contexts (Java).

Comment: Sorry - I didn't read that carefully enough. The next thing I would try is adding a `InputManager.HasGamePad` check ([docs here](https://doc.stride3d.net/latest/en/manual/input/gamepads.html)) into the code to see if Stride is seeing the DS4 at all or not. If it is, then it might be a mapping issue - some controllers have [unexpected interfaces](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/194745/33287).

Comment: Stride gives me only GameControllers and no GamePads. See my answer below. I assume this means it couldn't do the mapping. In my experience with SDL, it automatically does the mapping fine by default (it always returns 4 no matter the controller as the axis in events when left trigger is pressed for example), but I guess Stride is overriding that behavior for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer from what I figured out yesterday...

I was initially testing with a DS4 (official PS4 controller) and it was not working. The unaltered example did work when I switched to an "Afterglow" XBox controller though.

I had wrongly assumed SDL was used for input in the example. I edited the example to switch to SDL by changing `CSharpBeginner.Game\Code\VirtualButtonsDemo.cs` as follows:

```cs
using Stride.Engine;
using Stride.Games;

namespace CSharpBasics
{
    class CSharpBeginnerApp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var game = new Game())
            {
                // game.Run();
                game.Run(new GameContextSDL(new GameFormSDL(), 1280, 720, false));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With SDL, both controllers' input is available from scripts via the `Input.GameControllers` list. Stride only shows `IGameControllerDevice` instances and no `IGamePadDevice` instances.